# How to use Python with different SOCKS 5 Proxies?

Tags: python, linux, command-line, proxy

The following is what a hacker always does.

I have a list of SOCKS5 proxies and a list of username/password combos. I want to test the username/password list with different SOCKS5 proxies for a website www.example.com/login.html.

I am using Python 2.5 on CentOS 5.5.

How can I use [socksipy](http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/) or other modules?
Could you please give me a code snippet? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can trying using [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/)

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'www.example.com/login.php')
pycurlConnect.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, POST_DATA)
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, 'yourproxy')
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 8080)
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5)
c.perform()
```

The POST_DATA variable should look something like this depending exact arguments required by the login form:

```
POST_DATA = 'username=meatsafe&password=murderer'
```

Comment: Thanks! If I want to use different Socks5 proxies, should I use a FOR loop?

Comment: definitely :) read the file in line by line, I suggest you create method/function that takes in a line of the text, splits it into password and username and then runs the code i posted, so you can do it for every line in the file.

Comment: This method is almost fine, but DNS is not used through socks5, you need to use PROXYTYPE_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME (http://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2015/02/22/pycurl-through-tor-without-leaking-dns-lookups/)